# Paramiko does not allow to see Motion Streaming

Tags: python, linux, ssh, paramiko, motion

I'm using [motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_(surveillance_software)) to run a rudimentary livestream. It works perfectly when i start it in server side with:

```
sudo motion -c livestream.conf
```

This starts a video server in 8081 port and i can access perfectly from wherever i want inside my network.

The issue comes when i want to write a little script which will ssh using paramiko to server, start motion with the same command and open default browser directly in video stream url. Here the sample code:

```
import paramiko
import subprocess
import time

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('192.168.1.111', username = 'pi', password = 'raspberry')
ssh.exec_command('sudo motion -c livestream.conf')
time.sleep(4)
subprocess.call('xdg-open "http://192.168.1.111:8081"', shell= True)
ssh.close()
```

a pidof motion in server shows that the service is running,but i can't access it!!! Because motion is running, i think is not the common problem with sudo/paramiko, but i don't have any idea why this does not work.

WORKAROUND

Motion has a daemon mode. Enabling it from

```
/etc/default/motion
```

it starts on boot and i can call it perfectly with:

```
subprocess.call('xdg-open "http://192.168.1.111:8081"', shell= True)
```

But is not exactly what i'm looking for, because i'd like to launch(and close, but this will be another thread sure!!) the daemon, not just access the stream.
This workaround executes

```
/etc/motion/motion.conf
```

as daemon.I copied my motion script in there and everything good.
But when i try to start the script as daemon (not on boot, with the code above), it tells me that it can't create PID file. Everything done as root. I'm getting close to the answer by myself, just a little more.

Comment: Does the `motion` print any output/error messages?

Comment: Nothing gone wrong with motion, i will edit now with a workaround i got, but is not exactly what i'm looking for. The error comes with the web browser (connection refused)

Comment: How do you know that it does not print anything, if you are not reading the output?

Comment: Because at any given error, motion exits. If the process is running, motion has no errors... Or i suposed that!!

Comment: I'd check that. `ssh.exec_command('sudo motion -c livestream.conf > /tmp/motion.log 2>&1')` as well as any syslog.